# Pandas - Extract value from Dataframe based on certain key value

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe in the below format:

```
id, ref
101, [{'id': '74947', 'type': {'id': '104', 'name': 'Sales', 'inward': 'Sales', 'outward': 'PO'}, 'inwardIssue': {'id': '76560', 'key': 'Prod-A'}}]
102, [{'id': '74948', 'type': {'id': '105', 'name': 'Return', 'inward': 'Return Order', 'outward': 'PO'}, 'inwardIssue': {'id': '76560', 'key': 'Prod-C'}}]
103, [{'id': '74949', 'type': {'id': '106', 'name': 'Sales', 'inward': 'Return Order', 'outward': 'PO'}, 'inwardIssue': {'id': '76560', 'key': 'Prod-B'}}]
```

I am trying to extract rows that have `name = Sales` and return back the below output:

```
id, value
101, Prod-A 
103, Prod-B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str[0]` for first lists with [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) by values by keys of dicts:

```
#if necessary convert list/dict repr to list/dict
import ast
df['ref'] = df['ref'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df['names'] = df['ref'].str[0].str.get('type').str.get('name')
df['value'] = df['ref'].str[0].str.get('inwardIssue').str.get('key')

print (df)

    id                                                ref   names   value
0  101  [{'id': '74947', 'type': {'id': '104', 'name':...   Sales  Prod-A
1  102  [{'id': '74948', 'type': {'id': '105', 'name':...  Return  Prod-C
2  103  [{'id': '74949', 'type': {'id': '106', 'name':...   Sales  Prod-B
```

And then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df.loc[df['names'].eq('Sales'), ['id','value']]
print (df1)
    id   value
0  101  Prod-A
2  103  Prod-B
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. I however get this error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`